# Aggregations are empty with keyword tokenizer

Tags: php, elasticsearch, aggregate

For an aggregation result i have a field (type_name2) in my mapping with a lowercased filter and a keyword tokenizer. But if I set this filter and tokenizer  to the field my bucket is now empty. I have set this token and filter to ignoring spaces in words like: Fun X or Viva X.
Here my mapping (in PHP):

```php
'cars' => array(
                            'properties' => array(
                                /**'type_name2' => array(
                                    'type' => 'string',
                                    'fields' => array(
                                        'raw' => array(
                                            'type' => 'string',
                                            'analyzer' => 'keyword'
                                        )
                                    )
                                ),**/
                                'type_name2' => array(
                                    'type' => 'string',
                                    'analyzer' => 'keyword_lower'
                                ),
                                'type_kw' => array(
                                    'type' => 'float'
                                ),
                                'type_hp' => array(
                                    'type' => 'float'
                                )

                            )
                        ),
```

and the custom analyzer:

```php
'analysis' => array(
                'analyzer' => array(
                    'keyword_lower' => array(
                        'tokenizer' => 'keyword',
                        'filter' => 'lowercase'
                    ),
                    'nGram_analyzer' => array(
                        'type' => 'custom',
                        'tokenizer' => 'whitespace',
                        'filter' => array(
                            'lowercase',
                            'asciifolding',
                            'nGram_filter'
                        )
                    ),
                    'whitespace_analyzer' => array(
                        'type' => 'custom',
                        'tokenizer' => 'whitespace',
                        'filter' => array(
                            'lowercase',
                            'asciifolding'
                        )
                    )
                ),
                'filter' => array(
                    'nGram_filter' => array(
                        'type' => 'ngram',
                        'min_gram' => 2,
                        'max_gram' => 20,
                        'token_chars' => array(
                            'letter',
                            'digit',
                            'punctation',
                            'symbol'
                        )
                    ),
                )
            )
```

but the result of type_name2 is empty:

```php
'type_name2' => 
    array (size=1)
      'buckets' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
```

Any ideas, what is wrong?

Thx and regards
Stefan

Comment: Can you paste the query.